# tutorial for fk in view dropdown asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, view, foreign-keys

i am looking for a tutorial on how to put my foreign key in my create view as a dropdown or a way to select values from a different model.
I have been trying a bunch of tutorials over the past few days and all of them end with an error and I am losing my mind.
can anyone help me with a SIMPLE tutorial or show me how it's done?

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are explicitly off-topic. [ask] [Help] [mre] Please use standard spelling & punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> put my foreign key in my create view as a dropdown

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

Equipment:

```
public class Equipment
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Equipment Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }       
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

Department:

```
public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Department Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Equipment>? Equipment { get; set; }
    }
```

EquipmentsController:

```
 // GET: Equipments/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Department, "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

Equipment create view:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DepartmentId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DepartmentId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentId"></select>
            </div>
```

result:

[image]

You can read [one-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many)  and [Tutorial: Update related data - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  to know more.